# How to write query to find commalities such as customers who ordered in same dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

In a single table named [orders](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct2) with columns

```
OrderID CustomerID  .. OrderDate ..
```

I am looking for pairs of customers who ordered in same dates and would like to generate a result set such as

```
CustomerID1 CustomerID2 NumberOfCommonDates
```

my best guess so far was this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Orders]  AS a, [Orders]  AS b  
    WHERE a.OrderDate = b.OrderDate AND a.CustomerID <> b.CustomerID
```

Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySQL? The surrounding brackets tend to indicate that is is `sql-server` (or maybe `ms-access`).

Comment: @Jens edited the question and removed the sql server tag

Comment: Why is it an anomaly for different customers to place an order on the same date?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am confused a bit here, why do you think placing orders by different customers would be an anomaly ?

Comment: @WaterfrVilla . . . That is what the title of your question says.  Did you read my answer?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did read and appreciate it, however thought to accept the other similar answer posted earlier. Anyway I am still confused what kind of anomaly you are referring to?Delete anomaly, update or insert? I would appreciate it if you could explain as I am thinking i might be missing a learning opportunity here

Comment: @WaterfrVilla . . . I read "commalities" -- which is not an English word -- as "anomaly".  In any case, the `count(distinct)` is needed to correctly answer you question, which is why I provided a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking for pairs of customers who ordered in same dates and would like to generate a result set such as
>
> ```
> CustomerID1 CustomerID2 NumberOfCommonDates
> ```

Based on this, you want a self-join and aggregation, similar to other answers.  However, you need to be careful about customers who might make multiple orders on the same date.

The correct answer to that question is:

```
SELECT o1.CustomerID as CustomerID1,
       o2.CustomerID as CustomerID2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o1.OrderDate) as NumberOfCommonDates
FROM Orders o1 JOIN
     Orders o2  
     ON o1.OrderDate = o2.OrderDate AND
        o1.CustomerID < o2.CustomerID 
GROUP BY o1.CustomerID, o2.CustomerID
ORDER BY NumberOfCommonDates DESC;
```

The `o1.CustomerID < o2.CustomerID` is so the same pair of customers does not appear twice.

Based on the comments to other questions, I'm not sure this is what you really want.  However, I figured that there should at least be a correct answer to the question you actually asked.

If this is not what you want, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question and provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want.

Comment: will the answer that you'd mentioned would show two columns for customerid as in my answer i have used t.customerid<>t1.customerid in join condition it doesnt show two different columns by aliasing in select

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja . . . This produces exactly the three columns you mention in your question.

Comment: Yeah thats correct I saw but just wanted to know why on selecting the same way with join condition t.customerid<>t1.customerid doesnt give 2 seperate customerid columns

Answer (score 1):

You could self-join the table and use aggregation:

```
select
    o1.CustomerID CustomerID1,
    o2.CustomerID CustomerID2,
    count(*) NumberOfCommonDates 
from 
    orders o1
    inner join orders o2 
        on  o1.CustomerID < o2.CustomerID
        and o1.OrderDate = o2.OrderDate 
group by
    o1.CustomerID,
    o2.CustomerID
```

Join condition `o1.CustomerID < o2.CustomerID` ensures that you we not joining a record with itself, and also avoids duplicates in the result set like `('customerA', 'customerB')` vs `('customerB', 'customerA')`.

Note: this assumes that column `OrderDate` is of `DATE` datatype. If it's a `DATETIME`, then you would need to extract the date part before comparing, like:

```
date(o1.OrderDate) = date(o2.OrderDate)
```

Comment: check one of my edits i have posted the same already the only thing I missed is setting customerid <>o.customerid to '<'. Does the output show different columns for customerid as by using not equal to it considers customerid as common column and I think the columns which are added in join for any operation would be counted as single despite the alias

Comment: I am curious to know why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: I don’t really get what you say... Our queries are not the same: for example, mine uses aggregation, not yours.

Comment: Check my answers 3rd edit theres aggregation but thats not the question m asking rather I meant do adding columns in a condition makes those columns as single on joining eg in your join condition you have o.customerid<o1.customer I have used o.customerid<>o1.customer and in select o, o1..from table did you get different customerid columns by aliasing as in my case  it shows up as one customerid column

Answer (score 0):

@Arzev Mansuri was on the right track. Slightly modified you can get your three columns. and even two more with a first and last common date:

```
SELECT o1.customer, o2.customer, Count(*) cnt, min(o1.pdate) dmin, case when count(*)>1 THEN max(o1.pdate) END dmax
FROM tbl o1 
inner join tbl o2 on o1.pdate=o2.pdate and o1.customer<o2.customer
group by o1.customer, o2.customer
```

Sample output:

```
customer    customer    cnt dmin                dmax
Ginny       Hagrid      1   03.10.2019 00:00:00 NULL
Ginny       Harry       1   07.10.2019 00:00:00 NULL
Ginny       Hermiony    1   03.10.2019 00:00:00 NULL
Hagrid      Hermiony    1   03.10.2019 00:00:00 NULL
Harry       Ron         2   01.10.2019 00:00:00 01.10.2019 00:00:00
```

See demo here: https://rextester.com/DUGF43842

Comment: thanks but the output is not what I wanted. Where is the column representing common order dates? Where is customer 1 and customer 2?

Comment: @Gordon, thanks for your support! I completely edited my answer after I read Waterf Villa's comment. His criticism was justified w.r.t. my first version.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
     SELECT  t.customerid, t1.customerid, 
      Count(distinct *) as numberofdates
      FROM [Orders]  t join Orders t1
     on t.date=t1.date and t.customerid<> 
    t1.customerid group by customerid
```

Comment: @GMB I din downvote your answer based on “ if you had downvote my answer“ but was thinkin as per my 3rd edit answer my answer almost matches yours and I was getting only 1 column for customerid so wanted to check with if you would have got same 1 customerid column. I will remove my downvote on your answer. I thought it was same as mine

Comment: At the time when I wrote my answer you had edited yours already, and I did not check the previous versions of your answers. And even this previous version is different than mine: as explained in my answer (and in Gordon Linoff's), `o1.CustomerID < o2.CustomerID` avoids that the same pair of customer appears twice. I don't see the reson for the downvote here (but if you maintain that's fine for me! It's a free world).

Comment: No, actually I am unable to remove my downvote my vote is locked if you can edit your answer I will be able to remove the downvote and why does the above condition as compared to not equal works.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this

```
SELECT o1.customerid, o2.customerid, Count(*) as commonDates FROM Orders o1 join Orders o2 on o1.orderdate=o2.orderdate  group by o1.customerid, o2.customerid
```

Comment: Where do you define aliases o1 and o2?

Comment: From Orders o1
In this o1 is alias

Comment: When i execute your query on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct2 The resulting set has only two columns CustomerID commonDates

Comment: generates only one column for CustomerID!